# C# - Write file over FTP - how to set rights?

Tags: c#, unix, ftp

I wrote a .net C# application that writes text files to a unix machine, where an application reads it. My application writes files just fine to the target folder, but the unix application throws an error saying it doesn't have permission to read the file. 
When I send files using WinSCP, I can see the rights are rwxrwxrwx.
when my app sends files the rights are rw-r-----. 
I assume this is the reason.

Here is my code:

```
public override void WriteFile(string directoryName, string fileName, string text) {
     sshExec.RunCommand(@"echo """ + text + @""" > " + directoryName + "/" + fileName);
}
```

How do I set the rights so the other application can read the file?

Comment: If it is a file meant to be only read (not executed) then `rwxrwxrwx` is completely wrong.

Comment: You didn't even say what protocol you use to create files from within your application...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not FTP, this is usage of SSH shell.
You should append something like "& chmod 777 " + directoryName + "/" + fileName to your command.

Comment: Yeah, but this is what Yoav receives using WinSCP. He can simplt change a command to set other permissions.

Comment: Absolutely rightly observed, this is what he gets with his current WinSCP setup. All I say is it is not a good idea to do that. And we all know why. So why explain to him to do the same mistake in his own application? The goal should not be to get things working 'somehow', but to understand what you are actually doing.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use chmod 666 (or is chmod 6 enough?).

Comment: chmod 6 will give read/write access to 'other'. To give access only to owner, you should use chmod 600

Comment: Who is the owner? The app that wrote the file? I want to give another app the right to read and then delete the file from the folder.

Comment: This is exactly what I explained in the other answer to this question.

Comment: Actually you didn't give the answer to question but wrote some sentences about file permissions in Unix.

Answer (score -1):

You should create the file such that the reading user account has read permission to the file (so the account the reading application runs under). Since you don't specify any more details one can only guess what is required. So have a try with this:

- create the file as being owned by the user creating the file
- create the file as belonging to a group both users are member of, the creating and the reading user account
- create the file with the permissions `rw-rw-r--`

The best approach is to make both accounts member of some group and give the creating user that group as primary group. Then set that user accounts `umask` to the required permission masks value. That way the 'reading' application can also remove the file, if required. 
Of cause this is only a general rule of thumb, since you simply did not specify enough details what you really require.